# javascript validations before form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I added a javascript form validation to my code, before submitting it to the server. When the user clicks `submit` it should call the javascript validator before submitting it. If the validator gives the ok, only then should it submit. I seem to be doing something wrong, because it submits regardless of what the validator says...

Html:

```
<form id="start_form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this);">
    <ul class="error">
    </ul>
    <label for="title" >Title: </label><input value="{{ post.title }}" type="text" name="title">
    <label for="summery" >Summery/Prompt: <textarea name="summery">{{ post.summery }}</textarea>
    <label for="person">Participants Emails: </label>
    <ul id="people">
        <li><input type="text" name="person1"></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="person2"></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="add_group();"><img class="img_button" width="30px" height="30px" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Image/plus_button.png" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="remove_group();"><img class="img_button" width="30px" height="30px" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}Image/minus_button.png" /></a>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Start Game</button>
    <input type="hidden"  id="pn" name="pn" value="2">
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
function append_error(m) {
    c = "<li>" + m + "</li>"
    $('#error').appendChild(c)
    }
function validate_form(form) {
        var e = true
        if (form.title.value == "") {
            append_error("Title Required");
            e = false
        }
        if (form.summery.value == "") {
            append_error("Summery Required");
            e = false
        }
        for (i = 0; i < Number(form.pn.value); i++){
            email = $('[name="person"' + i++ + '"]').innerText
            if(email == ""){
                append_error("Email #" + ++i + " can not be blank")
                e = false
            } else if (!validateEmail(email)) {
                append_error("Email #" + i++ + " is not valid")
                e = false
            }
        }
        return e;
    }
```

Comment: Check your console for errors - your validate method may be crashing before e can be returned

Comment: I would, but the page reloads before anything can load to the console..

Comment: 1- you do not have `;` at the end of most of your `javascript` lines  
2- do not use `e` as a variable cause it's used for `events`, change the name of your `e` variable.

Comment: Add `console.log(m);` to `append_error()`. Set breakpoints in `validate_form()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery **doesn't** have **appendChild** method.
in your function:

```
function append_error(m) {
    c = "<li>" + m + "</li>"
    $('#error').appendChild(c)
}
```

this cause an error that submition eventually ignores your validation function

Comment: You are correct. The `.appendChild()` method is a native JavaScript function and not part of jQuery. [Reference](http://jsperf.com/native-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/4)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery so you can bind the submit event like so:

```
$('#start_form').submit(function(){
    return validate_form(this);
});
```

Comment: your code wouldn't work.. preventDefauld wont execute the submit,
and you need to return true or false

$('#start_form').submit(function(e){
    return validate_form(this);
});

Comment: @salexch - This is true. I have edited the example to work for them.  In truth I was expecting them to manually send the form submission.